# How to use a filter reversed, so: hide everything that contains the search-string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I want to use an angular filter but instead of showing the matches I want to hide the matches. How can this be done?

Comment: What are you ended up with? Would you post the code of the filter that shows the matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "negate" the filter:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filter: search && '!'+ search">{{item.description}}</p>
```

Here is a working plunkr with a demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/V3T5RGTRibMyfWZNOtYN?p=preview